# How to share data from Main Thread with Thread on the Common Pool

Tags: java

My idea is to share data from the main to the child thread (from the thread pool).

I found InheritableThreadLocal

Below is my example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InheritableThreadLocal<String> inheritableThreadLocal =
        new InheritableThreadLocal<>();
    System.out.println("Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Set data into inheritableThreadLocal: " + "ABCXYZ");
    inheritableThreadLocal.set("ABCXYZ");
    System.out.println();

    List<Integer> listIndex = List.of(1, 2);
    listIndex
        .stream()
        .parallel()
        .map(index -> {
            System.out.println("Thread name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - Get data from inheritableThreadLocal : " + inheritableThreadLocal.get());
            return inheritableThreadLocal.get();
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

When tested I have strange behavior when running this example in different Java versions.

Java 11.0.12:

```
Thread name: main - Set data into inheritableThreadLocal: ABCXYZ

Thread name: main - Get data from inheritableThreadLocal : ABCXYZ
Thread name: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3 - Get data from inheritableThreadLocal : ABCXYZ
```

Java 17.0.1:

```
Thread name: main - Set data into inheritableThreadLocal: ABCXYZ

Thread name: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1 - Get data from inheritableThreadLocal : null
Thread name: main - Get data from inheritableThreadLocal : ABCXYZ
```

I do not know why have different output on different Java version like this (The thread on the pool can not find any data from inheritableThreadLocal area).

Could anyone give me the answer?

Comment: A thread on the common pool is not inherited from your main thread, so I would think the behaviour in Java 11 is actually a bug. BTW, I assume this is an (over)simplified example, because normally you shouldn't use a thread local for the code as presented, you would just us a final or effectively final field for that.

Comment: As an aside, Java 11.0.12 and 17.0.1 are not the latest versions. Try with Java 11.0.16.1 and 17.0.4.1.